# Saving an audio file

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I'm building a script that is using voice recognition. It works, but the recognizing part often gives me bad results. So I thought I record the quality and check if a bad quality could be the result of my results.

i installed using

```
sudo pip3 install SpeechRecognition
sudo pip3 install PyAudio
```

the script:

```
import speech_recognition as sr    
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Ich höre zu....")
    audio = r.listen(source)

print(r.recognize_google(audio, language="de_DE"))
```

How can I change the script to save `audio` to a `wav/mp3`-file?

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Looks like you can call `get_wav_data` on your `audio` variable to obtain a byte string that represents the WAV data. You can then write it to a file. The documentation for `get_wav_data` is [here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#audiodata_instanceget_wav_dataconvert_rate-unionint-none--none-convert_width-unionint-none--none---bytes). You can write bytes to a file like so:

```
with open('your_file.wav', 'wb') as file:
    wav_data = audio.get_wav_data()
    file.write(wav_data)
```